How to start a persistent process for RemoteEvaluate
I can use the code to get a image from a remote machine:
myker = KernelConfiguration[
   "ssh://yode@192.168.1.57/usr/local/bin/wolfram", 
   "SshIdentity" -> "C:/Users/zyd19/.ssh/pycharmkey2"];

RemoteEvaluate[myker, Import["/home/yode/42.jpg"]]

But this code will cost 2s to start /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.3/Executables/wolfram each time. How to start a persistent process for RemoteEvaluate?

I know that WSTPServer might be a solution to start a persistent process, and it might be fine for a computational tasks
, but it's very very slow to transfer a image file from a remote host to local

I think you should be able to do ker = LaunchKernels[myker];, then use ParallelEvaluate[Import["/home/yode/42.jpg"], ker]. I didn't test it though, just assumed this from the documentation.

Just curious, why do you want to use a remote kernel instead of NFS?

@Domen This doesn't seem like a parallel task

@I.M. I've discussed some other methods here, but in this post, I'd like to know how to use remote kernel

@yode, well, if you specify just one kernel, than "parallel" is only the matter of semantics, right? Still, what don't you like about ParallelEvaluate approach?

You can also see inside RemoteEvaluate`RemoteEvaluate0 that RemoteEvaluate creates a one-time kernel object and deletes it afterwards.
